# Python 3.9 module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: big-sur, python

I am not sure if this is a Mac or Python issue, but on Python 3.9.6 if I import serial I get an error:-

```
>>> import serial
>>> x=serial.Serial()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
>>>
```

This works on Python 3.7.3

Both have the same version of pyserial

```
~$ pip3.7 list
Package            Version   
------------------ ----------
build              0.5.1     
certifi            2018.10.15
importlib-metadata 4.6.0     
numpy              1.17.3    
packaging          20.9      
pep517             0.10.0    
picod              0.0.6.0   
pip                19.0.3    
pyparsing          2.4.7     
pyserial           3.5       

~$ pip3.9 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
build      0.5.1
future     0.18.2
iso8601    0.1.14
packaging  20.9
pep517     0.10.0
picod      0.0.6.0
pip        21.1.3
pyparsing  2.4.7
pyserial   3.5
PyYAML     5.4.1
setuptools 56.0.0
toml       0.10.2
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix it?
EDIT

---

The namespace conflict may be the case, as I mistakenly installed `serial`, but on realising deleted it and installed `pyserial`

I tried deleting pyserial then got the following:-

```
>>> import serial
>>> help(serial)

Help on package serial:

NAME
    serial

PACKAGE CONTENTS


FILE
    (built-in)
```

On re-installing pyserial the error remains.

In the process I got the following warning.

```
~$ sudo -H pip3.9 install pyserial
Collecting pyserial
  Downloading pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 90 kB 3.7 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyserial
Successfully installed pyserial-3.5
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

Comment: What happens if you try `serial.serial()`?  (lowercase)

Comment: I suggest to read [serial > issues > Namespace conflict](https://bitbucket.org/davebelais/serial/issues/2/namespace-conflict)